# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I implemented a python script where I attempt to train a CNN on 2 features that I pass (sentences, probabilities) and predict whether the sentence is true or false. This is similar to the sentiment analysis task that is popular in this domain.

I am initially generating the word embeddings for the sentences which I have named as `triples`. Each triple/sentence has exactly 5 words. Hence, the word embeddings look as shown below.

```
Number of lines 1860
[[2, 194, 21, 17, 227], [12, 228, 22, 17, 229], [2, 230, 21, 17, 229], ...]
Shape of triple:  (1860, 5)
Shape of truth:  (1860,)
```

The triples are the sentences and the truths are the target class.

In my dataset, I have 3 fields (including the target class, `truth`) with the following 2 as features on which I'd like to train the model:

- Triples or the sentences (which I have converted as a vector of word embeddings).
- Probabilities for each sentence (which is a soft truth value in the range of [0,1].

Hence, I define a multiple input CNN model where the first input is the vector of word embeddings and the second input is a probability. Then I merge these 2 inputs and upto this point, everything seems to work fine.

> However, I am having trouble with passing both the arrays (`word embedding vector array` and the `probabilities` array which I have defined as `stv`.

I try fitting these two features as shown below.

```
model.fit([X_train_pad,np.array(stv[:-num_validation_samples])], y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25, validation_data=([X_test_pad,np.array(stv[-num_validation_samples:])], y_test), verbose=2)
```

However, I keep getting the following error.

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1302, 5)

#### Python Implementation

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import string
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from termcolor import colored
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, concatenate


# define documents
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv('../../data/triple_with_stv.csv')
sentence_lines = list()
lines = df['triple'].values.tolist()
stv = df['stv'].values.tolist()

for line in lines:
    tokens = word_tokenize(line)
    tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
    table = str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
    words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
    sentence_lines.append(words)

print('Number of lines', len(sentence_lines))
EMBEDDING_DIM = 200

#Vectorize the text samples into a S2 integer tensor
tokenizer_obj = Tokenizer()
tokenizer_obj.fit_on_texts(sentence_lines)
sequences = tokenizer_obj.texts_to_sequences(sentence_lines)

print(colored(sequences,'green'))

#define vocabulary size
vocab_size = len(tokenizer_obj.word_index) + 1

# print(colored(sequences,'green'))

#pad sequences
word_index = tokenizer_obj.word_index
max_length = 5

triple_pad = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_length)
truth = df['truth'].values
print('Shape of triple tensor: ', triple_pad.shape)
print('Shape of truth tensor: ', truth.shape)

#map embeddings from loaded word2vec model for each word to the tokenizer_obj.word_index vocabulary & create a wordvector matrix

num_words = len(word_index)+1

print(colored(num_words,'cyan'))

# first input model
emb = Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length)
input_shape = triple_pad.shape
print(colored('Input SHAPE for sequences','cyan'))
# print(input_shape)
visible1 = Input(shape=input_shape)
conv11 = Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu')(visible1)
pool11 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv11)
den1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(pool11)

# second input model
input_shape_stv = np.array(stv).shape
print(colored("Input Shape for stv: ",'cyan'))
print(input_shape_stv)
visible2 = Input(shape=input_shape_stv)
den2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(visible2)

# # merge input models
merge = concatenate([den1, den2])

# interpretation model
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs=[visible1, visible2], outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

#Split the data into training set and validation set
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.3

indices = np.arange(triple_pad.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
triple_pad = triple_pad[indices]
truth = truth[indices]
num_validation_samples = int(VALIDATION_SPLIT * triple_pad.shape[0])

X_train_pad = triple_pad[:-num_validation_samples]
y_train = truth[:-num_validation_samples]
X_test_pad = triple_pad[-num_validation_samples:]
y_test = truth[-num_validation_samples:]

print('Shape of X_train_pad tensor: ',X_train_pad.shape)
print('Shape of y_train tensor: ',y_train.shape)
print('Shape of X_test_pad tensor: ',X_test_pad.shape)
print('Shape of y_test tensor: ',y_test.shape)

print(colored('Training...','green'))

history = model.fit([X_train_pad,np.array(stv[:-num_validation_samples])], y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25, validation_data=([X_test_pad,np.array(stv[-num_validation_samples:])], y_test), verbose=2)

y_pred = model.predict_classes(x=[X_test_pad,np.array(stv[-num_validation_samples:])])
metrics = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')

print()
print(colored("Precision: ",'green'),colored(metrics[0],'blue'))
print(colored("Recall: ",'green'),colored(metrics[1],'blue'))
print(colored("F1: ",'green'),colored(metrics[2],'blue'))
```

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some guidance I received, seems like there is no need for me to perform any training on the probabilities (psl) layer. Hence, only the embedding layer needs to be trained with pooling and then the psl layer can be piped to the embedding layer and fitted to the model.

As such here's the model's modified portion of the working script.

#### Defining the Model layers

```
input1 = layers.Input(shape=(max_length,))
embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length)(input1)

cov = layers.Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu')(embedding)
pooling = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(cov)

input2 = layers.Input(shape=(1,))

concat = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([pooling, input2])

l1 = layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(concat)
out = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(l1)

model = models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=[out])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

#### Spliiting and fitting the Model

```
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.3

indices = np.arange(triple_pad.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
triple_pad = triple_pad[indices]
truth = truth[indices]
num_validation_samples = int(VALIDATION_SPLIT * triple_pad.shape[0])

X_train_pad = triple_pad[:-num_validation_samples]
X_train_psl = stv[:-num_validation_samples]
y_train = truth[:-num_validation_samples]

X_test_pad = triple_pad[-num_validation_samples:]
X_test_psl = stv[-num_validation_samples:]
y_test = truth[-num_validation_samples:]

print('Shape of X_train_pad tensor: ', X_train_pad.shape)
print('Shape of y_train tensor: ', y_train.shape)
print('Shape of X_test_pad tensor: ', X_test_pad.shape)
print('Shape of y_test tensor: ', y_test.shape)

print(colored('Training...', 'green'))

history = model.fit([X_train_pad, X_train_psl], y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25,
                    validation_data=([X_test_pad, X_test_psl], y_test), verbose=2)
```

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue of trying to use multiple inputs in deep learning models.

Answer (score 0):

The Conv1D layer in Keras expect to be feed by a 3D tensor (Batch_size, size1, size2)
By reading your error, it looks like that your are only feeding a 2D tensor.

If X_train_pad is (1302, 5) i suppose it's 1302 samples of (5, 1) embedding arrays.

So try to do the following before fitting your model :

```
X_train_pad = np.expand_dims(X_train_pad, -1)
```

Comment: Hi Thibault. I tried this. But I got this error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (1860, 5) but got array with shape (5, 1)`

Comment: You need to change change the input_shape accordingly
input_shape = (triple_pad.shape[1], triple_pad.shape[2])